# spl_autoload Class not found following namespaces directory structure

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I'm trying to use class autoloading in my project. This is what I wrote:

on main.php:

```
namespace myproject;

spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();

subspace\myclass::mystaticmethod();
```

on subspace/myclass.php:

```
namespace myproject\subspace;

class myclass {

    static function mystaticmethod() {

        ....

    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Class 'myproject\\subspace\\myclass' not found
```

So far I've only found a problem with case sensitive names in the documentation, so I switched to lowercase only but I get the same error. Why?

**[EDIT]** Using PHP 5.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem: The default include directory would be the full `namespace/subspace` path.

I've also found a good solution. From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php#92767:

```
<?php
    // Add your class dir to include path
    set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'..');

    // Make autoloader look for commonly used "myclass.php" type filenames
    spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

    // Use default autoload implementation
    spl_autoload_register();
?>
```

The default autoload implementation is written in C and is always slightly faster than a PHP one.